# OpenGL depth buffer maximum distance

Tags: opengl

Since the depth buffer pixels can only have colors from 0 to 255 (am I right?), the maximum draw distance would be limited by that bounds as well.

- Is that true?
- How do modern games work around this?
- What about values inbetween? Like 125.5?

Comment: Just in case your reading on this subject only covers Z and W buffers, there's also the logarithmic Z buffer, which has better coverage, although it isn't supported as fixed functionality (you'd have to implement it in a shader). http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/BranoKemen/20090812/2725/Logarithmic_Depth_Buffer.php

Answer (score 4):

- No its not true.  Its usually not even possible to use an 8-bit depth buffer due to the limited range it would provide.  The minimum is usually 16-bit with 24bit (saving the top 8 bits of 32 for a stencil buffer)  the most common.  Its also possible to use floating point depth buffers and 32-bit integer buffers.
- By using a greater depth.
- In the case of a value like 125.5 It would actually get rounded or truncated to 126 or 125.  However in general through OpenGL you would actually pass a depth value of between 1 and -1 (post projection and w divide) to  OpenGL.  This value is then sent to the OpenGL run time which converts it to an actual depth value.  This way you can change the bit depth of the depth buffer and everything continues to work.

Comment: One small addendum: It is also possible to use a 32-bit integer depth buffer on OpenGL 3.x cards.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: You are quite right. Edited. I tend to ignore 32-bit int buffers on the basis that while FP buffer only have 24-bits of accuracy the added dynamic range is far more useful than having the 32-bits, IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

Games that want to show a huge landscape usually use  a skybox / skysphere, ie. a flat image which gives the impression of greatness.

I remember Guildwars' main menu. It looks huge, but it you look closely, it's really a round texture.

Depth buffer pixels are here to make sure objects which are rendered further than an existing object are not drawn. If two objects have the same depth, they can choose to render it anyway, or not; either way is fine, you don't look for this much precision.